# hierarchical select to display taxonomy tree

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I need a similar module as hierarchical select to display taxonomy tree in my view because hierarchical select to drupal 7 doesn't work with views module.

Please help me !

Answer (score 1):

```
ASSIGN $child to an select list just set taxonomy id :
$taxonomy_vid = 3;
   /*** A HEADACHE CODE :p arrange the parent child taxonomies****/     
 /*      $tree_type =  taxonomy_get_tree($taxonomy_vid);   // taxonomy id here
    $childs["selected"]="Select a Value";
    //$childs[45]="New Launches/Projects";
    foreach($tree_type as $key =>$value) {  
$temp_ = taxonomy_term_load($value->parents[0]);       //IF parent is set already
                if($value->parents[0]==0) {                   //if no any parent taxonomy
                        if(is_object($temp_)==TRUE) {
                        if(isset($childs[$temp_->name])) {  //if array key is already set 
                                if(is_array($key)!=FALSE) { //if value is not an array
                                    $childs[$temp_->name][$key]=array($key=>$value->name);  // set the parent child array
                                }
                        }else {
                                if(is_array($key)!=FALSE) {    //if value is not an array
                                    $childs[$temp_->name][$key]=array($key=>$value->name);  // set the parent child array
                                }
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                            $childs[$value->name]=array();
                            $childs[$value->name][$key]=$value->name;
                            //drupal_set_message("-------<pre>".$value->name."</pre>-------");
                            }
                    }else {
                        //$temp_ = taxonomy_term_load($value->parents[0]); //IF parent is set already
                        $childs[$temp_->name][$key]=$value->name;       //$childs[$temp_->tid]=$temp_->name;
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick google search "views tree" will point you to [this module](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree), which most probably will get you going.